# running Service Swagger error " TypeError: Failed to fetch"

Tags: c#, swagger, windows-services, swagger-ui

I

I have a `Asp.Net Core MVC Api`, and published as a `Windows Service`. I have installed the Service locally and tried to run it from Chrome or Vista like this

```
http://localhost:5000/swagger/index.html
```

When I execute an Api Endpoint

[image: run]

I have this error

```
Failed to fetch.
Possible Reasons:

CORS
Network Failure
URL scheme must be "http" or "https" for CORS request.
```

This service has been deployed in several laptop without problems, but I am the only who has problems.. I do not think it is a problem in the Api, though I did some changes following every example I found.

I added in my program.cs

```
builder.Services.AddCors(o => o.AddPolicy("AllowAnyOrigin",
                      builder =>
                      {
                          builder.AllowAnyOrigin()
                                 .AllowAnyMethod()
                                 .AllowAnyHeader();
                      }));

.........

app.UseCors("AllowAllOrigins");
```

But still have the same problem.

I do not think it is a Cors or Service problem.

What could be the problem?

Thanks

Comment: any clue from application logs?

Comment: The App is not saving any log. The problem is when it is executed. I do not know if swagger has a log file. Thanks

Comment: What's the error message on the Console tab in the browser dev tools?

Comment: I had to comment line app.UseHttpsRedirection(); from my program.cs  But I do not understand why in other laptops it works and not in mine.. thanks